# Google Map Static Image API as Background Image?

Tags: css, google-maps, background-image

I'm trying to use a static Google Map as an inline CSS background image.

I'm referring specifically to this API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/

When I call the image on its own, in an actual `img` tag, it works perfectly. Adding it as a CSS background image, it doesn't. I can't find any documentation stating it shouldn't work.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
<div class="static-map" style="background:url('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Hollywood, FL, USA&zoom=7&size=420x200&maptype=roadmap
&markers=color:red%7C26.0112014,-80.14949009999998') no-repeat; background-size:cover;">
```

Does anyone know if there are limitations to using dynamically queried images like this or something? If you go directly to the URL, you'll see the image: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Hollywood,%20FL,%20USA&zoom=7&size=420x200&maptype=roadmap%20&markers=color:red%7C26.0112014,-80.14949009999998

**UPDATE** I've narrowed it down to the `&markers=color:red%7C26.0112014,-80.14949009999998` portion of the URL. Probably the `:` specifically, but encoding that doesn't work either...

Comment: works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/80z9b8jz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out - in addition to the code I pasted above, I also had an API key attached to the URL (which I didn't want to share for obvious reasons).

But Google doesn't seem to allow you to associate a localhost environment with an API key, and was therefore rejecting the request.

Ditching the API key until it goes to a production server is the only solution I can think of.